# how to make component or module in rails just like in joomla?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Just like in joomla I want to develop admin part where we can install and uninstall the module .. But i have no idea about that.. can anyone suggest me how to make independent component that can be install and unistall in one click by admin in admin part and it can be viewed by front part. I want to make this in rails. please someone give me some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is a framework, not a CMS. As such there isn't going to be any parallel to the Joomla! concept of the 'component'.

The closest thing you'll find in Rails-world is Engines.

See here for more detail: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html